# How do I save and restore a graphics context in Swift on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am porting a Mac app to iOS (and from Objective-C to Swift) and in Xcode I get several errors in the console stating that I'm using an invalid graphics context:

> : CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0.
>
> : CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0.
>
> : CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0.
>
> : CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0.
>
> : CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0.

However, even after removed the code where I was dropping down into Core Graphics and only using UIColor and UIBezierPath, the errors remain.

The only code where I'd used Core Graphics directly was to set shadows, but I strongly suspect my code for saving and restoring the graphics context in Swift is wrong:

```
if let context: CGContext! = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    let shadowColor = UIColor(white:0, alpha:0.75).CGColor
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, offset, blurRadius, shadowColor)
}

// Do drawing here...

if let context: CGContext! = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0), CGFloat(0.0), nil)
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
}
```

Would two different values for context be used here?  Is that the problem with this code?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: why do you grab the context twice for the same session? that is quote odd.

Comment: I knew something seemed wrong. You've confirmed it. I guess I shouldn't program with a migraine.

Comment: By the way, the context problem has been fixed -- stupid error on my part.  Now on to tackle autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I'm using to save and restore context in Swift:

```
// Save the graphics context
let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextSaveGState(currentContext)

... your graphics operations here ...

// Restore the previously saved context
CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Swift-3 Code to save and restore Graphic Context** :-

```
//To save current Context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.saveGState()

//To restore 
    context!.restoreGState()
```